# Can't pass any props when using Typescript with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I'm trying to pass props from my AllProducts, MenProducts etc. components to AddToCartButton component so that I can reuse AddToCartButton component. If I try to pass props like

```
<AddToCartButton id={product.id} />
```

I'm getting error:

Type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)

I've also tried to pass simple string as prop but it gives me the same error.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useAppSelector, useAppDispatch } from '../hooks/hooks'
import { fetchAllProducts } from '../store/features/allProducts/allProductsSlice'

import AddToCartButton from '../components/AddToCartButton'

export const AllProducts = () => {
  const product = useAppSelector(state => state.product);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchAllProducts())
  }, [dispatch])

  return (
    <div className="products-wrapper">
      <h1 className="products-wrapper__heading">
        All Products
      </h1>
      <div className="products-wrapper__products-cards-wrapper">
        {product.products.map(item => (
          <div key={item.id} className="product-card">
            <Link to={`/product/${item.id}`} className='products-wrapper__product-link'>
              <div className="product-card__img-wrapper">
                <img src={item.image} alt="product" className="product-card__product-img" />
              </div>
              <h3 className="product-card__product-name">
                {item.title}
              </h3>
              <h4 className="product-card__product-price">
                {item.price} €
              </h4>
            </Link>
            <AddToCartButton id={item.id}/>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
   )
}

export default AllProducts
```

Comment: In your `AddToCartButton` component you have to add the prop type that you are expecting to receive as a prop.

Comment: You can use an interface to define the types for the props or you can directly define the prop inside your component

Comment: How have you defined `AddToCartButton`? With what type for its props? That's essential, but missing, information for your question.

Comment: you should provide the code of <AddToCartButton id={product.id} />  so we get a better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're encountering is related to TypeScript and the way you're passing props to your AddToCartButton component. It seems that TypeScript is not recognizing the id prop in the AddToCartButton component.

// AddToCartButton.tsx

```
import React from 'react';

interface AddToCartButtonProps {
  id: number;
  // Other props if needed
}

const AddToCartButton: React.FC<AddToCartButtonProps> = ({ id }) => {
  // Your component logic here
  return (
    <button onClick={() => console.log(`Added to cart: ${id}`)}>Add to Cart</button>
  );
}

export default AddToCartButton;
```

In this example, we've defined an interface AddToCartButtonProps to specify the expected prop types for AddToCartButton. It includes an id prop of type number. Adjust the interface to include any other props your AddToCartButton component may need.

In your AllProducts component, make sure you import and use the AddToCartButton component correctly:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAppSelector, useAppDispatch } from '../hooks/hooks';
import { fetchAllProducts } from '../store/features/allProducts/allProductsSlice';

import AddToCartButton from '../components/AddToCartButton';

export const AllProducts = () => {
  const product = useAppSelector(state => state.product);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchAllProducts());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div className="products-wrapper">
      {/* ... your existing code */}
      {product.products.map(item => (
        <div key={item.id} className="product-card">
          <Link to={`/product/${item.id}`} className='products-wrapper__product-link'>
            {/* ... your existing code */}
          </Link>
          <AddToCartButton id={item.id} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mistake was in AddToCartButton component. I didn't define prop type in AddToCartButton component. Thank You all from your comments.

```
export interface IdProp {
  id: number
}

const AddToCartButton = ({id}: IdProp) => {
  const test = () => {
    console.log(id);

  }
  return (
    <button className="add-to-cart-btn" onClick={test}>
        Add To Cart
    </button>
  )
}

export default AddToCartButton
```